# Regex for Evalue substitution in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

**What I am trying to achieve is convert the Evalue 1e-2 to 0.01.**

```
my $cutoff = "1e-12";

if ($cutoff =~ m/^\de-{1}\d+?$/){
      $cutoff = s/e-/*10^(-/;
      $cutoff .= ")";
}  

print "$cutoff\n";
```

This is part of a bigger script and running it under `use warnings;` always gives me `Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at test.pl line 4, <STDIN> line 1.`

Does anyone spot the mistake here? I cannot seem to be able to do so.

Comment: Is `$cutoff = s/e-/*10^(-/;` supposed to be `$cutoff =~ s/e-/*10^(-/;`?

Comment: Thanks @Biffen...that was the mistake.

Comment: Note: The whole code should `$cutoff =~ s/^(\d)e(-\d+)$/$1*10^($2)/;`. No silly matching with m//, then matching again with s///.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for the advice. Will be taken on board for next time, but I've solved the issue using dan1111's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you get is because you used `=` rather than `=~` in front of the substitution operator.  You need:

```
$cutoff =~ s/e-/*10^(-/;
```

But that isn't the only problem here.  You would also have to `eval` the statement to get what you wanted, which would not only be a bad design, but completely unnecessary.  Perl natively treats values like `"1e-12"` as numbers, so you should not be doing this with a regex at all.  You can simply format the output:

```
printf '%d',$val;
```

That will convert `1e-2` to `.01`.  If you need to do create very long numbers like this, look into an appropriate module.

Comment: Ideally, you would have outlined that I need to use `$cutoff = sprintf ('%df', $cutoff)` with `d = any integer` in order to use it further in my script! Still, I accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you realise that "1e-2" is already a valid format for a number in Perl? you just need to persuade Perl to treat it as a number.

```
$ perl -E'$x= "1e-2"; say $x'
1e-2
$ perl -E'$x= "1e-2"; $x+=0; say $x'
0.01
```

Adding zero to it ensures that Perl knows it is a number.